# How to restrict Microsoft Account external login to a list of emails, or to one domain, in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, asp.net-identity

I have a web app that is intended for a list of people that use Outlook as their email provider. The web app uses Microsofts external login api. But anyone with a Microsoft email account can log in at the moment.

I am assuming this is an app setting within Microsoft dev portal, or an override somehow within may code. How can I filter the app's domain or have a strict list of accounts that can login?

Comment: AFAIK , portal doesn't have setting to control that , so the workaround may be restrict the account type after redirecting back to your client from Microsoft's login page .

Comment: @NanYu im completely new to .net. What gets called when the redirect takes place? Is there some override i can make in setup.cs maybe? Or its going to be a per page/view handle for that override. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK , portal doesn't have setting to control that , so the workaround may be restrict the account type after redirecting back to your client from Microsoft's login page .

I assume you are using `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.MicrosoftAccount`:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/microsoft-logins?view=aspnetcore-2.2

You can check whether the email account is outlook account in `ExternalLoginCallback`function of ASP.NET Identity :

```
[HttpGet]
[AllowAnonymous]
public async Task<IActionResult> ExternalLoginCallback(string returnUrl = null, string remoteError = null)
{
    if (remoteError != null)
    {
        ErrorMessage = $"Error from external provider: {remoteError}";
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Login));
    }
    var info = await _signInManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();

    var emailAddress = info.Principal.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.Email).Value;

    //Check whether this is outlook account .
    if (!"outlook.com".Equals(emailAddress.Split('@')[1]))
    {
        //return to error page and show error message 
    }
    if (info == null)
    {
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Login));
    }


    // Sign in the user with this external login provider if the user already has a login.
    var result = await _signInManager.ExternalLoginSignInAsync(info.LoginProvider, info.ProviderKey, isPersistent: false, bypassTwoFactor: true);
    if (result.Succeeded)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("User logged in with {Name} provider.", info.LoginProvider);
        return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
    }
    if (result.IsLockedOut)
    {
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Lockout));
    }
    else
    {
        // If the user does not have an account, then ask the user to create an account.
        ViewData["ReturnUrl"] = returnUrl;
        ViewData["LoginProvider"] = info.LoginProvider;
        var email = info.Principal.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Email);
        return View("ExternalLogin", new ExternalLoginViewModel { Email = email });
    }
}
```

Another way is checking in `OnCreatingTicket`event in middleware ,if login user is not outlook account , redirect user to login page again :

```
services.AddAuthentication().AddMicrosoftAccount(microsoftOptions =>
{
    microsoftOptions.Events = new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OAuth.OAuthEvents
    {
            OnCreatingTicket = ctx =>
        {
            var email = ctx.Identity.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.Email);
            if (!"outlook.com".Equals(email.Value.Split('@')[1]))
            {
                ctx.Response.Redirect("/");

            }
            return Task.FromResult(0);
        }


    };
    microsoftOptions.ClientId = Configuration["Authentication:Microsoft:ApplicationId"];
    microsoftOptions.ClientSecret = Configuration["Authentication:Microsoft:Password"];
});
```

Update :

If you are creating .net core application with `Individual User Accounts` template that means you are working with ASP.NET Identity :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio

ASP.NET Core 2.1 and later provides ASP.NET Core Identity as a Razor Class Library.  You can [scaffold Identity in ASP.NET Core projects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio) to modify the code and change the behavior. Or you can try the second solution above to modify the OpenID Connect middleware .

Comment: Lots of juice in this answer. Let me have a look at it and report back. Cheers

Comment: I have implemented `ExternalLoginCallback` in a base controller. All other controllers inherit from it. Is this meant to be an override, or I actually have to go into Microsoft dev apps and specify `ExternalLoginCallback` as the callback method?

Comment: no ,ExternalLoginCallback is the action which asp.net identity automatically create for you . Do you use the asp.net identity ?

Comment: I have the automatic Register and Login setup from the ASP.Net Core template created with my project. I then added Microsoft external login. From my understanding of what asp.net identity is I would therefore say `Yes I am using it`. Whats the way forward here Nan. I have am completely new to asp.net, please bare with me on connecting the dots

Comment: Also, I searched my project globally, and I do not have `ExternalLoginCallback` implemented anywhere. Where is it usually created? I am using ASP.Net Core 2.1 so maybe some of these methods are not autogenerated anymore..

Comment: see edited reply . You can either scaffold Identity in ASP.NET Core projects or try the second solution

Comment: I am now using the second solution. Seems to be getting into the if statement my authentication condition is not meant. How do I then completely end the session / process of creating the session. I have tried passing signinmanager through the Startup.cs constructor but that seems to only work for controllers. How can I end the current session?

Comment: `How do I then completely end the session / process of creating the session.` i'm afraid you can't , so that's a workaround . But your user will see his account isn't authenticated in your application since you make redirect to another page , so that identity system will not validate/decode the token and sign-in user .

Comment: With the redirect line there, the user is still signed in surprisingly, hence why im looking for a forced way to signout

Comment: Do you debug the application with `if (!"outlook.com".Equals(emailAddress.Split('@')[1]))` and confirm the redirect  and do you work with asp.net identity ?

Comment: Yes, I've debugged, and confirmed that it goes into the if block and goes through the redirect() code. But after I let it continue the page loads successfully with a username at top, and log out button next to it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185858/discussion-between-nan-yu-and-pnizzle).